# Exception while rendering form to insert new entity [symfony2]

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem to render view for creating new entity and can't find existing problem here being answered so I am going to ask...
My app has entity X that belongs to one entity Y and can have many entities Z.

When console runs, it executes well with all those relations.

> `php app\console doctrine:schema:update --force,`

After crud generating for entity X, listing page shows fine, but page for creating new record throws following exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, class 'Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\FormExtension' does not
>   have a method 'renderer->humanize' in
>   %path_to_app%\app\cache\dev\twig\16\16033db1d32d7d10db7a0d24db2f49938a4b2e9a63d231d90bf70d1969563fd0.php
>   line 880") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 232.

What could be the problem?

Update 1:

Exception's trigger lays in twig file where data is passed from controller.
At *{{ form_widget(form) }}*

Update 2:

//controller's method

```
/**
 * 
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="class_new")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Class();
    $form   = $this->createForm(new ClassType(), $entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

//Form class

```
class ClassType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Admin\MainBundle\Entity\Class'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'admin_mainbundle_classtype';
    }
}
```

// view

```
<form action="{{ path('class_create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this few weeks ago but now I spotted time for answering.
This was giving me headache before moving the app version from 2.1 to 2.8. Nowadays it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to empty the cache : `php bin/console cache:clear` and rerun your command.

If problem persit: look at in your controller if you are used a undefined function for exemple `renderer->humanize` and look `layout.html.twig at line 232.`

Comment: Problem persists despite cache clearing that I already was doing.

Comment: That layout is from dependencies. Controllers and other stuff are automatically generated by php app\console doctrine:generate:crud. I cannot change code from vendor directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in your controller and view.

So i tried to look for in `form_div_layout.html.twig` file and i found that function humanize is used there and the exception says that function isn't  defined.

So can you update your project by : `composer install`

form_div_layout.html.twig :

```
{%- block form_label -%}
    {% if label is not same as(false) -%}
        {% if not compound -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</label>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label -%}

{%- block button_label -%}{%- endblock -%}
```